# leading and trailing whitespace stripped from content of a text node when loading an XML file

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, whitespace

In actionscript 3, when trying to load an XML file like

```
<Element><Property> a </Property></Element>
```

the value in the node "property" will be just *"a"*, trailing and leading whitespaces are removed.

I did what http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-3125 recomends, with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described before, XML.prettyPrinting didn't work. 
Finally it got fix by adding `XML.ignoreWhitespace = false;`

After that line of code, the trailing spaces are not removed.

Comment: Just to be clear - you need to set both properties for it to work:         
`XML.ignoreWhitespace = false;
XML.prettyPrinting = false;`

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you put it inside CDATA tags, you'll get the whitespace.

```
<Element><Property><![CDATA[ a ]]></Property></Element>
```

Comment: This would probably work but the syntax is ugly. The idea was to keep my xml simple

Comment: It may be a few extra characters in your code, but it'd save you from the bugs grapefrukt mentioned. It's also the standard solution for something like this. http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_cdata.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
XML.prettyPrinting = false
```

Should work just fine, this is what I use for this exact problem. But do note that this is a global setting and can result in new bugs in other places in your app.

Comment: Just did some debugging again around this very issue.  ignoreWhitespace didn't have an effect.  It was solely the XML.prettyPrinting setting.